# How To Create A Wind Barb Map In Python From Geojson Data?

Tags: python, geojson, netcdf, weather

I have gridded winds data in geojson so all the geometries are points and each feature has wind speed and direction in its properties section - I would like to generate a wind barb map from this data.

I am totally new to python, but i found an excellent sample to do this at the unidata site:-

https://unidata.github.io/python-training/gallery/500hpa_hght_winds/

The only thing I think I need to do is modify it so that it can use geojson as a data source instead of a netcdf file.

Being completely new to this, I googled for a while and didn't find much to help with the geojson bit directly, but I did find that I could use geopandas to convert geojson to a shapefile then use gdal to convert the shapefile to a netcdf file. I am currently trying to work out how to modify the sample to use this data structure so I may encounter issues along the way.

I feel like I may have gone down a rabbit hole on this though, can anyone recommend a better way of doing this? Or alternatively, is this a valid method?

Here is a sample of the geojson:-

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "totalFeatures": 2124,
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "1bdffe7b-af88-4f33-a792-e3a2a53c08b3",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -120,
                    40
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "altitude": 38615,
                "flightLevel": 400,
                "temperature": -60.619,
                "windSpeed": 18.9,
                "windDirection": 352.7
            }
        },
...
```

And here is my code to do the 2-stage convert, but if I can go to the dataset straight from the geopandas dataframe that would be great!

```
import geopandas as gpd
import xarray as xr

df = gpd.read_file('./winds.json')
df[['altitude', 'flightLevel', 'temperature', 'windSpeed', 'windDirection', 'geometry']].to_file('./winds.shp')

from osgeo import gdal

inputfile = './winds.shp'
outputfile = './winds.nc'
# actually i haven't got this bit working yet, temp workaround is to use cmd line app (ogr2ogr -F netCDF './winds.nc' './winds.shp')
gdal.Translate(outputfile, inputfile, format='NetCDF')
ds = xr.open_dataset('./winds.nc')
```

Comment: Can you share the json file? I wonder wheter xarray can load dataset from json file? There is a possibility xr.Dataset.from_dict and json (even if geojson) is still close to dictionary...

Comment: Yeah I’d use geopandas to load the data and then set the x and y values as the index and then use `df.to_xarray`. If you set up a [mre] or even just give us more information about your data and how it’s structured we could work with that. But we do really need something more than your goal to work with :)

Comment: hi @msi_gerva, apologies i have added some sample geojson. ok great, it sounds like from what you are both saying that i might be able to miss out the second convert and go straight to an xarray from the geojson :)

Comment: i tried to add @MichaelDelgado to the last comment as well but it only allowed me to add a single notification

Comment: We get notified automatically if you respond to our comment so no need to @ two people. It would still be helpful to get actual code showing what you’ve tried and where you’re stuck. Thanks!

Comment: ah sorry i didn't realise it notifies you automatically, doh! no probs, i'll update the post with my code :)